# Perl - Convert a nested XML format to Java with recursion

Tags: java, regex, xml, perl, xml-parsing

I need to convert a nested XML format as below to Java using Perl:

```html
<invoke name="name1" operation="operation1" displayName="Invoke1" id="6">
  <input>
    <parameter name="Value" variable="Value"/>
    <parameter name="ID" variable="ID"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <parameter name="Return" variable="Return"/>
  </output>
</invoke>
<switch name="..." displayName="..." id="13">
    <case id="14">
        <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c1)]]></condition>
    </case>
    <otherwise id="106">
        <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="15">
            <case id="16">
                <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c2)]]></condition>
                <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="19">
                    <case id="20">
                        <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c3) >0)]]></condition>
                    </case>
                    <otherwise id="106"> </otherwise>
                </switch>
            </case>
            <otherwise id="107">
                <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="33">
                    <case id="64">
                        <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c4)]]></condition>
                    </case>
                    <otherwise id="108"> </otherwise>
                </switch>
            </otherwise>
        </switch>
    </otherwise>
</switch>
```

The expected output as the following:

```java
<invoke name="name1" operation="operation1" displayName="Invoke1" id="6">
  <input>
    <parameter name="Value" variable="Value"/>
    <parameter name="ID" variable="ID"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <parameter name="Return" variable="Return"/>
  </output>
</invoke>
if(c1) {
}else{
    if(c2) {
        if(c3) {
        }else{
        }
    }else{
        if(c4) {
        }else{
        }
    }
}
```

I think that it may be implemented using 4 steps:

1. Read XML file -> get the first switch1 block -> convert to if--else
2. Get case1 block and otherwise1 block of switch1 block
3. Implement recursion from step1 for case1 block and otherwise1 block
4. Read the rest of XML file and do the same from s1

It's actually difficult for me to do recursion in this case. Can some Perl experts help me here ?

Comment: You could try writing a function `process_switch` that takes an XML tree node (`XML::Twig` or `Mojo::DOM` would be good choices for parsing the file) and an indentation level. Call it with the top `switch` element in the file. Get the node's first `case` child. Get the `condition` child of the `case` and print it as `"\t" x $indentation . if( COND ) {`. If the `case` has a `switch` child element, call yourself recursively with an `$indentation+1`. Close the `if` bock and do the same with an `otherwise` if present.

Comment: Hi mbethke, thank you for spending your time to answer my question. My opinion is the same with you, but the difficulty is how to get Otherwise block if in the Case block has another sub-otherwise block. Can you help me write a sample perl code to solve this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Parser). I've used `Style => 'Subs'` because the only events I'm interested in are the start and end of `case` and `otherwise` elements, and non-blank character data

The array `@indent` has another element pushed onto it every time we descend into a block, and the last element is popped off when the block ends. The value of the last element in the array is the number of `case` elements we've seen so far at this level. That allows us to output `else if` for all occurrences after the first

I've wrapped the whole of the text in parentheses, because your third `condition` element contains `(c3) >0`, which doesn't make sense otherwise

I trust that it's clear enough for you to make any adjustments that you may need

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Parser;

my $parser = XML::Parser->new(
    Style    => 'Subs',
    Handlers => { Char  => \&handle_char },
);

my @indent = (0);

$parser->parse(*DATA);

sub indent {
    '    ' x $#indent;
}

sub case {

    print indent;
    print "else " if $indent[-1] > 0;
    print "if ( ";

    push @indent, 0;
}

sub case_ {

    pop @indent;

    ++$indent[-1];

    print indent, "}\n";
}

sub otherwise {

    print indent, "else {\n";

    push @indent, 0;
}

sub otherwise_ {

    pop @indent;
    print indent, "}\n";
}

sub handle_char {
    my ($expat, $string) = @_;

    print $string, " ) {\n" if $string =~ /\S/;
}


__DATA__
<root>
    <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="13">
        <case id="14">
          <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c1)]]></condition>
        </case>
        <otherwise id="106">
          <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="15">
            <case id="16">
              <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c2)]]></condition>
                <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="19">
                  <case id="20">
                    <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c3) >0)]]></condition>
                  </case>
                  <otherwise id="106">
                  </otherwise>
                </switch>
            </case>
            <otherwise id="107">
                <switch name="..." displayName="..." id="33">
                  <case id="64">
                    <condition expressionLanguage="..."><![CDATA[(c4)]]></condition>
                  </case>
                  <otherwise id="108">
                  </otherwise>
                </switch>
            </otherwise>
          </switch>
        </otherwise>
      </switch>
</root>
```

#### output

```
if ( (c1) ) {
}
else {
    if ( (c2) ) {
        if ( (c3) >0) ) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( (c4) ) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, thank you for spending your time to answer my question. I'm sorry if my question was not clear. Actually, my posted XML input is only a format, the actual input XML file is more complicated, it includes other same switch block and other XML tags. So that, I need a sub routine for getting block based on tag as well as @_ input and another sub routine for analyzing gotten block and do recursion in this.

Comment: @Kamogawa: As far as I can can tell my answer solves your problem. Why do you think it doesn't? Have you tried it?

Comment: When I run your code, there is a problem is that it keeps only data in [CDATA[....]], and deletes other block types except Switch block. For example, before Switch block I have other block :    `    <invoke name="name1" operation="operation1" displayName="Invoke1" id="6">
      <input>
        <parameter name="Name" variable="Name"/>
        <parameter name="ID" variable="ID"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <parameter name="Return" variable="Return"/>
      </output>
    </invoke>`  I want to keep this block to convert in another format.

Comment: In addition, for condition of if--else, can you tell me how to get condition (ex: C3 > 0 ) into a string to process. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Kamogawa: All of this is completely new. You didn't mention anything about it in your original question. I've spent a long time already working on your problem and I'm not going to do any more, especially as you don't appear to be making any effort at all of your own.

Comment: Hi Borodin,  I'm sorry because I did not explain clearly in my original question, and took your time in my problem. Actually, it's difficulty for me. I tried many times before, but I could not solve it. Anyway, thank you so much!